# 301 redirect of route - .htaccess code to remove appended query string of original route

Tags: .htaccess

I am unable to utilize other solutions found here and elsewhere to work in my case.

I have added a number of 301 redirects with the same syntax without issue, so I do not know why this is happening here.

Here's the redirect that's causing the problem:

```
Redirect 301 /controller/action/param http://newDomain.com/parameter
```

The result is:

```
http://newDomain.com/parameter?controller/action/param
```

I want to remove the query string, beginning at '?'

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try with below,

```
Redirect 301 /controller/action/param http://newDomain.com/parameter?
```

We are using empty query string.

Comment: Thank you very much Abhishek. This syntax removes the characters after the question mark, but still appends the question mark itself in the new route precisely as written in your answer. This is acceptable, although my preference is to remove the question mark also. Thanks again for giving your time to resolve my issue.